Why the result is different? Numpy Slicing and indexing
Basically I want to obtain a part of the variable "cubote". I tried two methods that should work in the same way, but it didn't.
My code:
   import numpy as np

   # Create a 3x3x3 cube
   cubote = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)

   # Compare the results
   result1 = cubote[0:2,0:2,0:2]
   result2 = cubote[0:2][0:2][0:2]

   print(result1)
   print("Shape of result1:", result1.shape)

   print(result2)
   print("Shape of result2:", result2.shape)

OUTPUT:
result1:
   [[[ 0  1]
     [ 3  4]]

    [[ 9 10]
     [12 13]]]
   Shape of result1: (2, 2, 2)

result2:
   [[[ 0  1  2]
     [ 3  4  5]
     [ 6  7  8]]

    [[ 9 10 11]
     [12 13 14]
     [15 16 17]]]
   Shape of result2: (2, 3, 3)

I expected the two results to be the same.
I refer to the result 1 makes sense, but result 2 did not work as I expected.
WHY?

numpy does not change python syntax or squence of operations. So each indexing operation, [...] is a separate python call. So you need to understand what each does. [2] is different from [0:2].

The difference in the results between result1 and result2 comes down to how indexing works in NumPy.
Explanation of result1:
result1 = cubote[0:2, 0:2, 0:2]

In this case, you are applying slicing across all three dimensions at once. This means you are extracting a sub-cube with indices in the ranges [0:2] in all three dimensions, which gives you a 2x2x2 cube.
Explanation of result2:
result2 = cubote[0:2][0:2][0:2]

Here, you're doing something different. Let’s break it down:
1.cubote[0:2] extracts the first two "layers" (2D arrays) from the cube, so the result of this step is:
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])

This is a 2x3x3 array.

Then, [0:2] is applied to this result, which further extracts the first two rows (along the first axis) of the new array. But since the array is already 2x3x3, this doesn’t reduce the size, and you still have a 2x3x3 array.

Finally, [0:2] is applied again, but since you're now operating on the first axis of the current 2D slices (each of shape 3x3), it doesn't behave as expected because you've already "peeled off" dimensions.


Key Difference:

Slicing across all dimensions at once (as in result1) extracts the correct sub-cube.

Chained indexing (as in result2) performs indexing sequentially, and since each index slice operates on the current result rather than on all dimensions at once, you don't get the same shape or result.


You should use slicing in all dimensions simultaneously, like in result1, to obtain the expected 2x2x2 sub-cube.
cubote[0:2, 0:2, 0:2]: Extracts a sub-cube across all three dimensions.
cubote[0:2][0:2][0:2]: Extracts slices sequentially, leading to an unexpected result.
To get consistent results, always apply slicing across all dimensions at once if you are trying to extract a subarray.

cubote[0:2] is an array of shape (2, 3, 3). If you add further [0:2]s to this array, you will again and again take the first 2 (i.e. all) elements from the first axis of this (2, 3, 3) array. So nothing will change. Even cubote[0:2][0:2][0:2][0:2][0:2][0:2][0:2] will yield the same result.

To complete the existing answers, for successive slicing to be equivalent to simultaneous slicing you would have needed to consider the dimensions in the slices.
This means, slicing [0:2], then slicing the second dimension [:, 0:2], then the third one [:, :, 0:2]:
result2 = cubote[0:2][:, 0:2][:, :, 0:2]
print(result2)
print("Shape of result2:", result2.shape)

Output:
[[[ 0  1]
  [ 3  4]]

 [[ 9 10]
  [12 13]]]
Shape of result2: (2, 2, 2)

Of course, slicing everything at once (cubote[0:2, 0:2, 0:2]) is more convenient (and also more efficient since you're not creating intermediates).
%timeit cubote[0:2,0:2,0:2]
232 ns ± 1.08 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

%timeit cubote[0:2][:, 0:2][:, :, 0:2]
555 ns ± 1.35 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)


In addition to Stef's and BlueLightning's answers, which already cover the actual question perfectly, I would like to shed some light onto where your misconception ("i tried two methods that should work in the same way") probably arises from:
Consecutive indexing done in the way that you use consecutive slicing for result2 will actually achieve the expected result. Take, for example:
import numpy as np

cubote = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape(3, 4, 5)

print("indexing_result_1:", cubote[1, 2, 4])
# >>> indexing_result_1: 34
print("indexing_result_2:", cubote[1][2][4])
# >>> indexing_result_2: 34

What is happening with consecutive indexing is that with each applied index, the corresponding dimension (or "axis" in NumPy) will be removed:

The result of cubote[1] is a 2-dimensional array, with shape (4, 5).
The result of cubote[1][2] is a 1-dimensional array, with shape (5,).
The result of cubote[1][2][4] is a scalar.

Through the consecutive removal of dimensions, the successive index values will be applied to the exact same (remaining) dimensions as is done with all index values in cubote[1, 2, 4] in one and the same call.
The crucial difference between consecutive indexing and consecutive slicing is therefore the removal of dimensions in indexing, while dimensions are retained in slicing (and thus the same dimension will be sliced over and over again in your result2, as has already been explained in the mentioned answers).
